# Xcode objective-C: Why does UIImage imageNamed method reset all other images to default locations?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

When I use the imageNamed method, it resets all of my other images in my app back to their default locations, which I don't want to happen. For example, I have a music clef with an image of a note(note.png) that the user is allowed to drag to a new location on the clef. Below the music clef is an image(finger.png) displaying where your fingers should be placed on a given instrument to play the selected note. So when the user drags the note from note A to note B, I try to change the finger image from "fingerA.png" to "fingerB.png" by using the imageNamed method. It works great for changing the finger image because "fingerB.png" is now displayed, but my note.png gets moved back to the default location that it started at when the app loaded(in this case note.png goes back to noteA and "fingerB.png" is displayed, even though note.png is hardcoded to go to the coordinates that would place it on noteB's position).

A code snippet to give you an idea of how I'm doing this is below.

```
    -(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
    {
        //location.y is where the user stopped dragging the note
        int yloc = location.y; 
        if(yloc > 40 && yloc <=80)
        {
            //noteImage is just the note.png that is being move on clef
            noteImage.center = CGPointMake(120,60);
            fingerImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"fingerB.png"];
        }
    }
```

I've tried swapping the two lines of code and changing the finger image first and then setting the coordinates of the note image after. I've also tried saving off the coordinates of the note image and restoring them at a later point. I've started to run out of ideas and am hoping someone who has more knowledge with objective-C or Xcode has some words of wisdom on how to get around this. Thanks!

Comment: I guarantee you that `imageNamed` is not the cause of this. You must be doing something else as well - whereabouts in your code do the locations get set in the first place? What else happens after the drag event? You're either calling some set up code again, or segueing to another instance of the same view controller, at its default state.

Comment: The note image location gets set in the viewDidLoad event, and there is nothing else in the code that happens after the drag event, what I showed above was all I'm doing at the end of the drag. So unless there is some event being fired after the drag that I'm unaware? I'm still very confused :S

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using Autolayout in your storyboard (its the default for ios6 and up). This will reset the position of your UI elements whenever the view controller's view is laid out again. All sorts of events could cause this, setting the image of an image view could well be one of them.

With Autolayout, you don't set frame or center, but edit constraints instead. It's probably easier for you to turn off Autolayout than do this - in interface builder, select the file inspector and uncheck "use Autolayout".

If you want to keep using Autolayout, you'll need to define constraints (x position and y position), make outlets to them and edit the `constant` properties of the constraints instead of setting a frame directly.